# Очень долго приходит заявка с сайта mail()

Tags: php

У меня почему-то очень долго приходит заявка с сайта на мой емейл подскажите как исправить.

```
    {div class="form">
<form id="application" action="send.php" method="POST" name=" application ">
<div class="place">
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="applicationName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Имя"  required /></div>
<div class="place">
<input name="user_city" type="text" id="applicationName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Город"  required /></div>
<div class="place">
<input name="email" type="text" id="applicationEmail"  placeholder="E-mail" maxlength="30"  required /></div>
<div class="place">
<input name="phone" type="text" id="applicationTelephone" placeholder="Телефон" maxlength="12"  required/></div>
<div class="btn"> <div class="but"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="page-button page-button__white">Обратний звонок </button></div></div>
</form>}





<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to = "poma234@gmail.com"; 
$from = "ro.ta241@gmail.com";


$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$user_city=$_POST['user_city'];

$subject = "Форма отправки сообщений с сайта ";


if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
show_error("<br /> Е-mail адрес не существует");
}


$mail_to_myemail = "Здравствуйте! 
Было отправлено сообщение с сайта! 
Имя отправителя: $first_name
E-mail: $email
Город: $user_city
Номер телефона: $phone
Текст сообщения: $message


$headers = "From: $from \r\n";

/* Отправка сообщения, с помощью функции mail() */
mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo "Сообщение отправлено. Спасибо Вам " . $first_name . ", мы скоро свяжемся с Вами.";
echo "<br /><br /><a href='https://lipro.tech'>Вернуться на сайт.</a>";
}
?>
<!--Переадресация на главную страницу сайта, через 3 секунды-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function changeurl(){eval(self.location="https://lispro.tech");}
window.setTimeout("changeurl();",4000);
</script>
```

Comment: Может ли это быть связано с хостингом?

Comment: Это связано с хостингом.

Comment: Да, это хост, скорее всего письмо встает в большую очередь. И функия mail возвращает boolean, поэтому писать что письмо отправлено стоит после проверки отправки `if (mail(...)) { echo 'Успех'; }`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev кстати не факт. PHP отправляет письмо, проверку проходит успешно, но письмо приходит минут через 30-40. У самого хостинга тоже есть очередь на отправку.

Comment: Ну это как дополнение, не связанное с вопросом. Она не пройдет, если в очередь не встанет, если например хост вдруг отрубит возможность отправки.